# Ensure *all* code paths return either a valid JDBC connection or throw an Exception (forbid "null")

Tags: java, jdbc, nullpointerexception

Objective: ensure *all* code paths either *throw* or return a valid connection; I am trying to explicitly avoid at all costs the connection object to ever return as "null".

This is the best I could come up with:

```
public class JdbcConnectionManager {
  public static class JdbcConnectionFailureException extends Exception {
    private static final String JDBC_CONNECTION_INVALID_MESSAGE =
        "JDBC connection invalid, checked with timeout value of: "
            + JdbcConnectionManager.JDBC_CONNECTION_VALIDATION_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS;
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    public JdbcConnectionFailureException(String message) {
      super(message);
    }
    public JdbcConnectionFailureException(Throwable throwable) {
      super(throwable);
    }
  }
  private static int JDBC_CONNECTION_VALIDATION_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS = 3;
  public static Connection getJdbcConnection(
      JdbcConnectionParameters jdbcConnectionParameters)
      throws JdbcConnectionFailureException {
    try {
      if (jdbcConnectionParameters
          .driverNeedsHelpRegisteringUsingClassForName()) {
        Class.forName(jdbcConnectionParameters
            .getClassForNameDriverRegistrationString());
      }
      Connection jdbcConnection =
          DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcConnectionParameters
              .getJbdcConnectionUrl());
      if (!jdbcConnection
          .isValid(JdbcConnectionManager.JDBC_CONNECTION_VALIDATION_TIMEOUT_IN_SECONDS)) {
        throw new JdbcConnectionManager.JdbcConnectionFailureException(
            JdbcConnectionManager.JdbcConnectionFailureException.JDBC_CONNECTION_INVALID_MESSAGE);
      }
      // TODO: perform further validation on the connection
      return jdbcConnection;
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
      throw new JdbcConnectionManager.JdbcConnectionFailureException(
          classNotFoundException);
    } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
      throw new JdbcConnectionManager.JdbcConnectionFailureException(
          sqlException);
    }
  }
}
```

Am I rock-solid here? Is there a better, more concise/elegant/robust way to ensure "connection" is never "null"?

EDIT:

I added a jdbcConnection.isValid() check but I have left out input validation. I'll do that in the actual code.

Comment: I should probably null-validate input to getJdbcConnection too, oops... (i.e. check JdbcConnectionParameters jdbcConnectionParameters as it comes in)

Comment: Not necessarily. If it's documented that the argument may not be null, the best you can do in this case is throwing a NullPointerException.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be much clearer to just return the connection from inside the try block:

```
public static Connection getJdbcConnection(
              JdbcConnectionParameters jdbcConnectionParameters)
                                     throws JdbcConnectionFailureException {
    try {
        if (jdbcConnectionParameters.driverNeedsHelpRegisteringUsingClassForName()) {
            Class.forName(jdbcConnectionParameters
                                .getClassForNameDriverRegistrationString());
        }
        return DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcConnectionParameters
                   .getJbdcConnectionUrl());
        // TODO: perform further validation on the connection
    } 
    catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
        throw new JdbcConnectionManager.JdbcConnectionFailureException(
            classNotFoundException);
    } 
    catch (SQLException sqlException) {
        throw new JdbcConnectionManager.JdbcConnectionFailureException(
            sqlException);
    }
}
```

EDIT : to answer your question about dead code:

jdbcConnection can NOT be null at this place, because if it was null, a NPE would have been thrown at the line

```
if (!jdbcConnection.isValid(...))
```

Comment: Why wouldn't it? All code paths either return a connection, or throw a declared exception.

Comment: Well, because I am stupid and I overlooked something. :) Sorry! (next time, I'll have Eclipse open before saying nonsense..)

Comment: Wow... you are right! It can't be NULL because of the NPE "exit"! I would have not caught that so quickly alone... awesome!

Answer (score 1):

Looks good to me.

A couple of things you could do to improve your code.

First, you should always put your preconditions first. In your case check method inputs first, like `jdbcConnectionParameters`

Second, as all caught exceptions are rethrown, you can catch all exceptions by catching `Exception` and rethrow with your custom exception.

Something like:

```
try {
      if (jdbcConnectionParameters.driverNeedsHelpRegisteringUsingClassForName()) {
        Class.forName(jdbcConnectionParameters.getClassForNameDriverRegistrationString());
      }
      jdbcConnection = DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcConnectionParameters.getJbdcConnectionUrl());
} catch (Exception exception) {
      exception.printStackTrace();
      throw new JdbcConnectionManager.JdbcConnectionFailureException(exception);
}
```

Comment: No, no, no. Catching Exception is an extremely bad practice. If there is a bug that causes a NPE inside the method, I prefer getting an NPE rather than a JdbcConnectionFailureException. If you want to throw the same exception for several types of caught exceptions, use the Java 7 multi-catch block: `catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e)`

Comment: @JBNizet I agree with you in catching `Exception` and I agree that defensive programming is bad to some people. Coming from real time embedded software world, I strongly believe it is useful in this case. At least my application does not crash when an uncaught exception error occurs.

Comment: I completely agree that I should be checking inputs as preconditions, very good point. And do that assertively as first thing. Design by contract, Bertrand Meyer :)

Comment: @Robottinosino Yep, that's what I meant. Eiffel, Contracts... Bertrand Meyer :)

Comment: It's not about crashing or not crashing. It's about throwing the appropriate exception. By your logic, you should enclose each line of code inside a try catch block, and rethrow your own checked exception instead of the runtime exception that would be thrown in case of a bug.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is fine, but for me you are overcomplicating a bit:

```
public static Connection getJdbcConnection(
  JdbcConnectionParameters jdbcConnectionParameters)
  throws JdbcConnectionFailureException {
    try {
      if (jdbcConnectionParameters.driverNeedsHelpRegisteringUsingClassForName()) {
        Class.forName(jdbcConnectionParameters
            .getClassForNameDriverRegistrationString());
      }
      return DriverManager.getConnection(jdbcConnectionParameters.getJbdcConnectionUrl());
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException classNotFoundException) {
      throw new JdbcConnectionManager.JdbcConnectionFailureException(classNotFoundException);
    } catch (SQLException sqlException) {
      throw new JdbcConnectionManager.JdbcConnectionFailureException(sqlException);
    }
}
```

Also consider using `DataSource` and `JdbcTemplate` from [spring](/questions/tagged/spring). Also do not `printStackTrace()` if you are passing that exception as cause and rethrowing - it will be logged twice.

Comment: You are absolutely right, I would be logging twice in that case. I can't use Spring, unfortunately. Is there a better framework with this kind of Jdbc validation already done apart from that?